# Initialize shared_preferences in Flutter test

Tags: flutter

I'm just starting testing my Flutter app and I'm getting some errors.

This is the code to test:

```
late SharedPreferences prefs;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await detectFirstTime();
  ...
}

Future<bool> detectFirstTime() async {
  var music = prefs.getBool('music');
  if (music == null) {
    await prefs.setBool('music', true);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and this is my test:

```
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  late SharedPreferences prefs;

  testWidgets('detects the first time we open the app',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final bool firstTime = await detectFirstTime();
    expect(firstTime, true);
  });
}
```

the error:

> LateInitializationError: Field 'prefs' has not been initialized.

NOTE: this `prefs` is the one I have declared in the widget, not in the test. I have it declared like that to easily import it from the rest of the widgets without initiating it again. Is it considered a bad practique maybe?